# date_select tag doesn't get stored in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to let the user select his birthday with:

```
<% form_for :user, :url => users_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_select :birthday, :start_year => 2010 , :end_year =>1920, :discard_day => true %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that it doesn't get saved... birthday is a date field in the users table and to save it I call

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.save
```

what could be the problem?

Thanks
Maechi

Comment: Have you checked your validations? what does @user.valid? and @user.errors return?

Comment: I do the validation with captcha... just one line: @user.valid_with_captcha?

Comment: @user.valid? is true and @user.errors gives an empty hash...

Comment: Just for grins, try outputting the contents of params[:user] from the controller (in a raise, for example) just to ensure the birthday field is coming through. Then, from the app console try setting the field manually with this value. I've had this point me in the right direction many times.

Comment: As I use ruby mine I can debug the app and see what's in the variable... there are 3 birthday fields called birthday(1i) = "1981", birthday(2i) = "8", birthday(3i) = "1" But I can't reference to this kind of variable... params[:user][:birthday(1i)] doesnt give me anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to discard day option that you choose. 
See the html code of date_select tag.You will get clue from there.

Comment: Hi Gsoni, it's the same problem aswell if I remove the :discard_day tag! The date devides itself to 3 different params and doesnt get written in the correct variable!

Comment: I mean to say that collect the values of different params that are formed by date_select tag. Then create a date from those collected params and then pass these formated date in to your model to save it.

Ex:- month = [:user]["birthday(1i)"]
     year =  [:user]["birthday(2i)"]
   make a date in format you want because here you will need a default day.So add a day whatever you want.
   bdate = "1/month/year"
 and convert it into datetime object then bdate canbe saved.

Comment: Great! I tried to use params[:user][:birthday(1i)] but that didn't work... what worked was params[:user]["birthday(1i)"] Thanks a lot!